Modify USB adapter 5 V, 1 A or any 5 V mobile charger to output 4.5 V, 500 mA or 900 mA
I have a trimmer which charger is lost, and now I want to charge it with my mobile micro-USB charger. The issue I am facing is that it has two 1.5V batteries connected in series. When I try to charge it by my 5 V, 1 A or any mobile charger, one of the diodes become so hot on the PCB. However, there are two diodes 1N5819 connected in series. The first diode will not get hot, but the next one becomes hot. The battery will charge okay, no issue.
My friend has the same trimmer as mine. Its charger has 4.5 V, 900 mA output written on it. When I connect his charger, the diode doesn't get hot and is at normal temperature.
So what should I do to drop 5 V to 4.5 and also to reduce current so that diode temp not go so hot, and it will charge fine when using any type of 5 V mobile adaptor?


If one diode gets hot and the other does not then they are not in series or there is something else that we don't know about.

What more does the charger say than 4.5 V 900 mA? ⎓ or ~̅?

There are two questions here, why does only one diode get hot if they are in series, and why does it not get hot when a supply that's 0.5 V less is used?
If the diodes are in series they should have the same current through them, and being the same type of diode they should have approximately the same voltage drop across them. Heat is generated by power, and power is voltage times current, so if voltage and current are the same they should both dissipate the same amount of heat. That only one gets hot indicates that there is some difference between them. Are you sure they are both 1N5819? If they are then one of them is likely to be bad.
That the diodes don't get hot when using the lower voltage may be explained by the charge on the batteries when you tried it with that supply. If the battery is charged by the 5 V supply and then you try the 4.5 V supply the diodes could be reverse biased because the battery voltage is higher than the supply voltage. Even if one diode is bad the other would still be reverse biased and no current would flow therefore no heating. You could try running the trimmer for a while to reduce the battery charge and then try charging it with the 4.5 V charger and see if the diode gets hot.
The best thing to do would be to get a multimeter with a diode test function and actually test the diodes. With the charger not connected and the power switch off you should be able to test them in circuit. They should measure open when the red lead is on the striped end, and a small voltage, maybe 0.2 V to 0.5 V, with the black lead to the striped end.

There are two 1.5V AA Batteries connected in series...  and i have checked both diodes are 1N5819 as you can also see in the picture of both diode connected in series.

Ok i will try to run the trimmer for while and reduce voltage then i will check the diode

@Asmar Do you have a multimeter to check voltages? I forgot it was two 1.5 V batteries, that shouldn't charge high enough to reverse bias the diodes, the batteries might just be charged enough to not draw much current from the 4.5V supply. I'll wait for your results and amend my answer accordingly.

i have check the voltages on first diode putting red probe on strip side give voltage 0.32V and putting black probe on strip side give -0.3V... on second diode putting red probe on strip side gives 0.34 V and putting black probe on strip side give -0.35V

You can't really reduce current in this case without also reducing voltage. A linear regulator or DC/DC converter sounds a bit like overkill here; try a standard silicon diode rated for at least 2A in series between the charger and the razor. That should drop 0.5-0.6V, check the datasheet for exact Vf.

Can you tell me the which silicone diode is best here any info becuz iam new in electronics

Actually standard silicon might be too much forward drop. A medium power schottky like a 1N5820 would work well I think.

Ok i will try to use that diode... thanks mate
